# Is it necessary to call another setitimer function, when I first ignore the alarm signal and then catch it

Tags: c, linux, signals

I was lost in the two situation, but I can't find out the difference between them. I want to catch the alarm signal, at the start of the code, so I called the `settimer` function and the `signal(SIGALRM, move_)`, and the program worked correctly.

It is one situation that in the signal handler function, I first ignored the signal, before return I called signal(SIGALRM, move_), and the program caught the signal again.

**Note, in the situation ,I was not necessary to call the setitimer again, and the program can catch the alarm signal**

The other situation, in the `SIGIO` handler , I typed 'p',and the alarm signal was ignored. Then I typed 'c', I want to the program catch the alarm again.

**Note,but at this time , I must call setitimer function  again, if I wanna the alarm be caught**

Why the difference? What cause the difference?

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define MESG  "xxxxxxx"
#define BLANK "           "
#define COLUMS 100
int settimer(int);
void move_(int);
void keyboard(int);
int x = 80;
int y = 0;
int dir = -1;
int ppp = 0;
int main(void)
{
int flag;
struct itimerval old;
initscr();
crmode();
noecho();
clear();    


signal(SIGIO, keyboard);

fcntl(0, F_SETOWN, getpid());
flag = fcntl(0, F_GETFL);   
fcntl(0, F_SETFL, (flag | O_ASYNC));

signal(SIGALRM, move_);
settimer(150);
mvaddstr(y, x, MESG);
refresh();

while(1){
    sleep(1);
    getitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &old);
    //printf("P %d %d %d %d\n", (int)old.it_value.tv_sec, (int)old.it_value.tv_usec, (int)old.it_interval.tv_sec, (int)old.it_interval.tv_usec);

    if (ppp == 1) { 
        signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);
        ppp = 0;
    }

    if (ppp == 2) {
        settimer(150);
        signal(SIGALRM, move_);
        ppp = 0;
    }
}

endwin();
}

int settimer(int msec)
{
struct itimerval time_val;
long sec, usec;

sec =  msec/1000;
usec = (msec%1000) * 1000L;
time_val.it_interval.tv_sec = sec;
time_val.it_interval.tv_usec = usec;
time_val.it_value.tv_sec = sec;
time_val.it_value.tv_usec = usec;

return setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &time_val, NULL);
}   

void move_(int signum)
{
signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);
mvaddstr(y, x, BLANK);

if (dir == -1 && y == 0) 
    dir =1;

if (dir == 1 && y == LINES - 1)
    dir = -1;

y += dir;
mvaddstr(y, x, MESG);
refresh();
signal(SIGALRM, move_);
}

void keyboard(int signum)
{
int c;
c = getch();

if (c == ' ')
    dir = -dir;

if (c == 'p')
    ppp = 1;

if (c == 'c')
    ppp = 2;
}
```

According to the adivce from @user3629249, I have modified my code, excepting the tab and displaying in signal handler.

@Oldest Software Guy suggests using sigaction,  but signal and sigaction  appear to be the same in this situation. For simplicity, I also use signal.

For solving my doubt, I test my code in a mount of ways, by modifying the detail in the code.I  observe the appearance of them and  make a conclusion, which seems acceptable and reasonable.I try to find some useful information about the timer detail to support my opinion, but I fail.

Below is my procedure.

If I setitimer and signal(SIGALRM,SIG_IGN) at begin of my code, call getitimer in the while loop, the it_interval isn't 0 but the it_value is 0 always,in other words,  the it_interval not reset the it_value.

In move_ function in my code, I firstly signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN) and signal(SIGALRM, move_) before returning, the signal will arise as usual.But when I remove the signal(SIGALRM, move_), after the last it_value decrementing to 0, it_interval will not reset the it_value. On the other hand, if I don't remove the signal(SIGALRM, move_), at that time it_value decrementing to 0, the status of alarm  signal is being caught, so the it_interval will reset the it_value and the program work well. Using the getitimer can find this phenomenon.

Below is my conclusion.

I call setitimer, the timer begin.When the it_value decrementing to 0 at every time, the timer will check whether there is a catch for the signal.If not, the timer disable (it_interval don't reset the it_value forever). If I wanna catch the signal again after the timer disable , I need call setitimer again.At this time, the timer still exist but the status is disable.(This kind of  disable isn't equal to the kind of disable , which it_value is 0 and it_interval is 0)

But at the window of it_value isn't 0 , I change the catching the signal, I don't need call setitimer again.

Considering the reliability, I had better call setitimer before reset the signal.

The conclusion seems to strange, if you have interesting about it, testing it by yourself.

Comment: a few notes on the code:  1) main only has 3 valid formats, all the formats have a 'int' return type, never 'void'  2) for readability by us humans, indent the code, never use tabs for indenting, suggest 4 spaces.  3) for readability by us humans, insert a blank line between functions and between code blocks.  4) using 'new' for a variable name is a very bad idea as it is a reserved word in C++.

Comment: more notes:  the signal handler function should not be manipulating the display, rather it might set a flag that the main program loop can check and act upon.

Comment: under gcc/ubuntu, compiling the posted code raises 10 warnings that need to be fixed.   Suggest when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for instance surrounding text with back-tics  is not a valid comment. use /* ... */)

Comment: 1) Inside a signal handler routine, never to much more than set a flag for the main code to interpret.  Calling libc functions is a no-no.  2) It is impossible to write a correct program using the Berkeley signal(3) package; it is fundamentally flawed.  Instead use the AT&T sigaction interface.  The Berkeley architecture has a built-in race condition which cannot be avoided; as a result the program will look good, pass your tests, and then fail under the most stressful production conditions.  Use sigaction, it's worth the effort.

Comment: I doubt the signal function isn't the place where the problem is.I translate my code using sigaction function, but the problem still exist.I have used another way to test my code, using getitimer function get the value of timer in the while function in main and replacing the pause function by a sleep function. The program ignore the SIGALRM and the print the value getting from gettimer. I find a very strange appearance that when the current it_value expired ,it_value can't reset by the it_interval no longer.The it_interval is not 0, but the it_value is 0 alway.

Comment: @OldestSoftwareGuy: POSIX defined `sigaction()` in part because AT&T `signal()` (at least in 7th Edition UNIX) was primitive and BSD `signal()` behaved more like `sigaction()` — at least in respects such as not necessarily resetting the signal handler.  I'm not sure whether `sigaction()` was previewed in SVR4 before POSIX finalized it, or whether POSIX defined it an SVR4 followed.  Yes, using `sigaction()` is usually a good idea, and `signal()` can behave quite surprisingly differently.  But the history is contorted at best.

Comment: I make a conclusion, because the size of comment window, I modify my question and place my conclusion at the end.